# jQuery report wrong top/left position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have all my elements on page set to absolute positions, which is all integer. And although Chrome report correct position e.g. top 100 left 15, jQuery report a very odd coordinate  top 99.99999332427979 left 15.454545021057129. What gives?

**EDIT:** For some unknown reasons, it got back to work perfectly, reporting exact whole number. I really don't know what is going on, but it must have something to do with margin-top,   margin-left, border-top-width and border-left-width, since they are parsed as floats in jquery position() function. In my case, I don't do any animation, so this problem is not animation-related

Comment: Is there animation being run on the element you are getting the position of? It sounds like rounding errors of the `animate()` method.

Comment: We couldn't possibly know without seeing your code. Make sure your #wrapperDiv is position: relative;

Comment: Like the other guys say, we cant help with seeing some code. For example, both .position() and .offset() give the correct coordinates in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/MV6Dh/)

Comment: the weird thing is the position is still reported correctly in Chrome's Inspector. Sorry guys but the code is not allowed to be publicised, and it's too large to post anyway.

Comment: a quick fix could be to use the operator `toFixed()` but of course it may be not always working, at least in a project it's always been working. I noticed is the best choice compared to other solving ways like `~~`, `Math.floor()` or `Math.ceil()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but I think it has something to do with floats and the calculations in jQuery.

Float is an data type that holds numbers. Either big numbers or numbers with a lot of decimals. Looking at the numbers, I'm pretty sure jQuery uses floats.

Little fact about floats: they are inaccurate. VERY inaccurate which often results in odd looking numbers like these.

It seems that google uses more accurate data types to calculate positions. You must be wondering, why isn't jQuery using an accurate datatype? That's in fact a really easy question. jQuery uses calculations that results in decimal numbers (easing etc) with all kinds of forms of data (pixels, points, percents, etc). If jQuery would use whole numbers only and you'd be working with percents only, you'd get a pretty ugly animation. Thats why I think jQuery is using floats, and that explains the dodgy numbers.

Finally, the distance of an jQuery animation is calculated using a distance and time. Lets say, jQuery "updates" your DOM 60 times per second and you'd wish to move your element 60 pixels in a single second, it would move your element a single pixel on every "update". However, what if you wish to move your element 61 pixels in one second you don't have to think hard to know that it'll result in a dodgy number... Your element would move 1.01666667 pixels per second. This also explains why I think jQuery uses floats...

I'm afraid there's little you can do about it really. You could just round the numbers.

Comment: Yes, rounding the numbers is easy. But it makes anything that rely on CSS sprite looks weird.

Comment: I don't think there's anything else you can do, unless you wish to rewrite jQuery or know how to "fix" the float being inaccurate.